# mysql cluster with PHP

Tags: mysql, php, mysql5, mysql-cluster

I have a very common LAMP stack with about 6-7 machines with PHP and Apache and a few machines with MySQL server (master+slave, sharding)

I am exploring options of moving to MySQL Cluster. I couldnt find a lot of information about it and reviews and benefits online specially when used in a webapp with PHP.

Can someone share their thoughts or difficulties / experiences with MySQL Cluster.

Actual Question: Is it a good idea to move to mysql cluster or stick to slaves + sharding for a live webapp.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm part of the Cluster team in MySQL, and have some resources to share with you in determining whether MySQL Cluster is a good fit

To learn more about cluster in web apps, there is this guide which covers the architecture of Cluster and common use cases in the web (note, registration required):
http://mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/mysql_wp_scaling_web_databases.php

Useful resources are posted as follows. The Getting Started Guide in the Technology Overview section can get you up and running with Cluster in 15 minutes and the Evaluation Guide in the Technical Whitepapers section can help you determine if Cluster is the right fit:
http://mysql.com/products/cluster/resources.html

You can also reach the developers through the Cluster forum - forums.mysql.com/list.php?25 - for any questions

Hope these resources are useful to you